# Keras ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 923679, 63), found shape=(None, 63)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, reshape

I have tried to change my input according to the error posted in the link, yet still receiving the same error.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, LSTM, BatchNormalization, Bidirectional, LayerNormalization
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from keras import regularizers
import re
from keras.layers import Dropout
```

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=100,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(923679,63)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=100,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=100,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=100,return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

```
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1]))
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0],X_test.shape[1]))
Y_train = np.reshape(np.array(Y_train),(Y_train.shape[0]))
Y_test = np.reshape(np.array(Y_test),(Y_test.shape[0]))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eOHv.png)

```
model.fit(X_train,Y_train,epochs=50,batch_size=50, verbose=2, validation_data = (X_test, Y_test))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64fG1.png)

Comment: try adding flatten layer

Comment: Could be worth mentioning Keras in the title and clearing it up a bit for make it easier for others to help out.

Comment: What is the output of `X_train.shape`? Also please use `tensorflow.keras` as prefix while importing the keras libraries - `from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential`
`from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, LSTM, BatchNormalization, Bidirectional, LayerNormalization` `from tensorflow.keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical`
`from tensorflow.keras import regularizers`

Answer (score 0):

The error points to this line in your code.
`model.add(LSTM(units=100,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(923679,63)))`

You have to give the shape as (None,63) as mentioned by the error.